# Why LG GT540 after boot it disconnects with ADB

Tags: usb, adb

Why when my phone LG GT540 is running and seen by ADB after bootup it disconnects (not from PC just from ADB, as PC still can see it it Device Manager) after few seconds after bootup sequence?

The problem is occuring only with GT540, tested other device - HTC - works fine.

The key could be USB drivers, but tried many of them official and handmade.

Also I've tried running phone in "Recovery" or "Safe" Mode - when LG firmware updated my phone via USB with no major problems with connection, hovewer I cant use ADB over this "Safe" mode, can't I?

Comment: Have you enabled USB Debugging in the Settings?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: What device is it detected as after boot? Mass storage? Generic device? Which Windows version?

Comment: WIndows 7 64b, http://i47.tinypic.com/1hufy1.gif (tis undetected device is probably a SD Card)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people have had their device turn on the mass storage mode by itself.

Verify that you haven't enabled `Mass storage only` mode in `Settings -> SD Card & storage -> Mass storage only`, then reconnect & restart adb daemon.

Comment: Why to restart adb deamon?

Comment: To verify it's listening actively on the port.

Comment: It wont help...

Comment: Actually after reboot of PC it worked! Thanx!